# IntelliJ IDEA Have actuall tabs when tab

Tags: java, tabs, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ. When I tab it actually uses spaces and not tabs. Can't figure out how to change that.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why this has been down-voted. It seems like a perfectly valid question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/changing-indentation.html

> **To toggle between tabs and spaces**
>   On the main menu, choose *Edit* | *Convert Indents* , and then choose *To Spaces* or *To Tabs* respectively.